# sapui5: how to implement colspan in sap ui5 table

Tags: sapui5

i'm using a footer for one of columns, whos length is more then the width of the column.. and end results i can't see the full text.

```
                     <footer>
                     <VBox>
                        <Label text = "Total 1 abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz"></Label>
                        <Label text = "Total 2"></Label>
                        <Label text = "Total 3"></Label>
                        <Label text = "Total 4"></Label>
                     </VBox>
                     </footer>
```

i'm just wondering if i can do a colspan so that the text can be seen properly. this is very simple in traditional html>table.. something like below:

```
<td colspan="2">TEXT GOES HERE</td>
```

but i dont see any option for sap.m.column to make use of colspan. is there any way to achieve this?

tnx

Comment: is using jquery the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Table controls are not designed for layouting. If you need this you should use sap.ui.layout.MatrixLayout. The other option would be using Text control instead of label to make text wrap.

Comment: Tnx for ur post. But Text wrapping doesn't solves my rqmnt. Does any control outside sap.m.Table so that it sticks there and I can display text + total?

Comment: Any layout control or toolbar with solid design or footerText property of the table?

Comment: the code given in the initial post was part of table->footer. so u suggest me to use layout control? which ones?